# Can't connect to SQL server from Container

Tags: python, docker, mariadb

My Python container is throwing the error below when trying to connect to my SQL DB hosted on a server:

```
mariadb.OperationalError: Can't connect to server on 'xxxxxxxxxxx.jcloud-ver-jpc.ik-server.com' (115)
```

I am trying to run my container from my server as well. If I run the exact same container from my machine, I can connect to the SQL DB.

I am new to Docker, so just for info, here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY alpha_gen alpha_gen
COPY poetry.lock .
COPY pyproject.toml .

# install basic utils
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl -y
RUN apt-get install gcc -y

# install MariaDB connector
RUN apt install wget -y
RUN wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup
RUN chmod +x mariadb_repo_setup
RUN ./mariadb_repo_setup \ --mariadb-server-version="mariadb-10.6"
RUN apt install libmariadb3 libmariadb-dev -y

# install poetry
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.local/bin"
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true

# install dependencies
RUN poetry install

CMD poetry run python alpha_gen/main.py --load_pre_process
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Try to connect with the IP address. Maybe you have a problem to resolve the hostname `xxxxxxx.jcloud-ver-jpc.ik-server.com`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Apparently there is a private port to use for communication from the server and a public port for communication from outside the server. I was using the public one so it was not working.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).